# How to show values of a Javascript Set() in Stackblitz console?

Tags: stackblitz

I've been using stackblitz as a scratchpad for learning and testing javascript. I find it very convenient to use the real time console updates while logging out lines of code.

One problem I've encountered is how the console outputs the results of a Set() method.

For example

```
let numbers = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3];
numbers = new Set(numbers);
console.log(numbers); // expect: Set(3) {1, 2, 3}
```

The output of the console.log(numbers) in the chrome inspector is `Set(3) {1, 2, 3}`
However, the output of the stackblitz console is just `Set {}`

I suppose this is just a quirk of the SB console or is there a workaround that doesn't involve opening the chrome inspector to view the contents of the Set()?

Answer (score 1):

Worst case you can simply do:

```
console.log([ ...numbers ]);
```

This will spread `numbers` into an Array, and the Array will be logged.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned in my question that I've essentially been doing what you propose. Just asking if perhaps I'm missing something or does SB just have a limitation that other online editors (jsfiddle, codepen, etc) do not appear to have. I much prefer SB but for this one quirk.

Comment: Sounds like an idiosyncrasy of stackblitz's `console.log` implementation to me...